# NullPointerException when trying to convert list back into an array

Tags: java, arrays, list, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a NPE when trying to convert my list back into an array.
I debugged through and found that my list is getting an extra value that is null.

Why is the happening and more importantly how do I fix the issue?

```
List<String> attrList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(attrArray))

//I loop through and remove unnecessary elements

 attrArray = attrList.toArray(attrArray);

//next line uses attrArray and is throwing NPE.

Here's what I found through debugging,

attrList = [1, 2, 3]

attrArray = [1, 2, 3, null]
```

Comment: What is `attributeList`? You complain that it contains a `null`, but you haven't posted any code that refers to it.

Comment: Is it me or are some lines redundant? `attrArray = attrList.toArray(attrArray);` for example. I doubt that's the actual code.

Comment: @LewsTherin. So, you missed the last line yeah??

Comment: @Ruakh. Sorry attributeList is actually attrArray.

Comment: @LewsTherin: Why shouldn't `attrArray = attrList.toArray(attrArray)` be actual code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try replacing

```
attrArray = attrList.toArray(attrArray);
```

with

```
attrArray = attrList.toArray(new String[attrList.size()]);
```

I think it will work, because what you have right now is

```
List<String> attrList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(attrArray));
// I loop through and remove unnecessary elements
attrArray = attrList.toArray(attrArray);
```

and JavaDoc of [`List#toArray(T[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) states (highlights by me):

> If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare (**i.e., the
>   array has more elements than the list**), the element in the array
>   immediately following the end of the list is set to `null`. (This is
>   useful in determining the length of the list only if the caller knows
>   that the list does not contain any null elements.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently unable to test the solution but I've no doubt this was the issue.